# Understanding how to initialize constructors in the Multiple Inheritance

Tags: c++, constructor, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance, ctor-initializer

I having hard time in solving those kind of question. In an exam I going to take in a few days, they show a program in `C++` which has Multiple Inheritance:

```
struct X {
    X(){cout << "X" << endl;}
};

struct A : virtual X {
    int i;
    A(){cout << "A" << endl;}
};

struct B : A {
    int i;
    B(){cout << "B" << endl;}
    virtual void f() {cout << "f" << endl;}
};

struct C : A {
    int i;
    C(){cout << "C" << endl;}
    C(int i){cout << "C2" << endl;}
    virtual void g() {cout << "g" << endl;}
};

struct D : virtual B, virtual C {
    int i;
    D( int i) : C(i), B() {cout << "D" << endl;}
};
```

And show some code from main:

```
D* d = new D(2014);
C* c = d;
B* b = d;
```

And than ask "what will be the output?" I don't need the solution, I can always 
 just run or debug it but I need to understand the intuition because I will not have the debugger with me on the exam. Now I know the algorithm I need to follow:

> 5 Initialization shall proceed in the following order:
>
> — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class as
>   described below, virtual base classes shall be initialized in the
>   order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the
>   directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the
>   order of appearance of the base class names in the derived class
>   base-specifier-list.
>
> — Then, direct base classes shall be initialized in declaration order
>   as they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of
>   the mem-initializers).
>
> — Then, nonstatic data members shall be initialized in the order they
>   were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order
>   of the mem-initializers).
>
> — Finally, the body of the constructor is executed. [Note: the
>   declaration order is mandated to ensure that base and member
>   subobjects are destroyed in the reverse order of initialization. ]

But I really having bad time solving them, it does not make any sense. Is it possible to show the intuition, maybe a trick or tip on solving those kind of questions? Maybe to show dark corners? Maybe somehow to write down all the classes/structs, write the vbase classes somehow in order to easy see to output?

Comment: Show your attempt, we'll see your mistakes and we can explain them to you.

Comment: Off topic but... in any \`sane' build environment the code shown would probably fail to compile as the `D` ctor attempts to initialize the base classes `B` and `C` in the wrong order.

Comment: Why do you need any intuition? Just follow the quoted algorithm as is.

Comment: @G.M. I disagree. In any sane program, it shouldn't matter!